# How to make `\bm{<number>}` work with newtxsf and lualatex?

Tags: fonts, luatex, bm

I get bold `0` as exected when I compile the following code with `pdflatex`.
However, I get normal (not bold) `0` with `lualatex`.
Is there any workaround to get bold `0` with `lualatex`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxsf}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}

$0$
$\bm{0}$ % OK with pdflatex, but not with lualatex

$a$
$\bm{a}$ % always OK

$\beta$
$\bm{\beta}$ % always OK

\end{document}
```

pdflatex: [image]

lualatex: [image]

My environment is

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016)
LuaTeX, Version 0.95.0 (TeX Live 2016)
bm: 2016/07/07
newtxsf: July 4, 2015
```

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: newest version of what? I can't currently run updates but there is nothing in the list that looks related.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I think my environment is up to date (I added version information).

Comment: @kshramt please ignore my previous (now deleted) comment:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer never underestimate the potential for human error, i deleted my comment:-)

Comment: looks like an undocumented feature, I'll  post later....

Comment: This is now fixed in the release due this month, thanks for the clear test file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{newtxsf}
\usepackage{bm}

\makeatletter

\def\bm@umathchar#1#2#3{%
\@tempcnta#2\relax
\count@\bm@table
\ifnum\count@=\z@
  \bm@gr@up\boldmath{\Umathchar#1 #2 #3 }%
\else
  \ifnum\count@=\m@ne
  \else
    \advance\@tempcnta\count@
  \fi
  \bm@xadd{\Umathchar#1\space
                     \the\@tempcnta\space\space
                     #3\space}%
\fi}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$0$
$\bm{0}$ % OK with pdflatex, but not with lualatex

$a$
$\bm{a}$ % always OK

$\beta$
$\bm{\beta}$ % always OK

\end{document}
```